# Anime.js How to animate the transition of an element to the center of the page?

Tags: javascript, css, anime.js

There is an element that, when the page is loaded, should smoothly move to the center from the left side of the screen, depending on the resolution of the device. TranslateX parameter: 0, does not accept percent. It is necessary that this be implemented precisely on the Anime.js plugin.

Comment: Hi julieta and welcome to SO. Please edit your question and include the code related to the question. If possible, create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to work with. Regarding your question; while you can't use percentages, you can however calculate the distance of the animation. Something like `window.innerWidth / 2` will give you the center of the screen. Which, depending on the dimensions of your element, might also be translate value of your animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it using the transition property in CSS, example:

```
.example {
  transform: ....;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

this is the simple use case of this, but you'd have to adapt it to your existing code because you didn't post any for me to drop this into.